# How to specify the default scope in Spring's applicationContext.xml to request scope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scope

I want to make all beans request scoped by default, however the Spring documentation says that the default scope is Singleton.  (sections 3.4.1 and 3.4.2 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html)

I want to declare the default scope to be request scoped.

This is the closest thing I have found so far -- it's a defect that has not been touched in some time. jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-4994?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#issue-tabs

Answer (score 3):

There is no *default-scope* Attribute defined in spring-beans.xsd file. But according To [BeanDefinition](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html) API

> **Extended bean factories might support further scopes**.

And [WebApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) - A extended ApplicationContext supports *request* scope

> Supported in addition to the standard scopes "singleton" and "prototype"

So just make sense To use request scope when you have a WebApplicationContext. And if you want To register of all beans defined in WebApplicationContext as request scoped, **you must define a BeanFactoryPostProcessor**

```
public class RequestScopedPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {
        for(String beanName: factory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            BeanDefinition beanDefinition = factory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);

            beanDefinition.setScope("request");
        }
    }
}
```

And do not forget register your BeanFactoryPostProcessor

```
<bean class="RequestScopedPostProcessor"/>
```

But keep in mind

> This method **does not consider ancestor factories**. It is only meant for accessing local bean definitions of this factory

So The BeanFactoryPostProcessor defined above just overrides scope property whether your bean is defined in your WebApplicationContext

**UPDATE**

> is there a way to then override **some of the default "request" scoped beans to be singleton scope** ?

Again you should use The same BeanFactoryPostProcessor provided above. I am not sure but I Think The only way you can set up its scope is by using *beanDefinition.setScope* method. And **There is a lot of useful methods you can retrieve information about any bean**. See [ConfigurableListableBeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.html) such as

- getBeanNamesForType

...

```
/**
  * Suppose Service is an interface
  *
  * And you want to define all of Service implementations as singleton
  */
String [] beanNameArray = factory.getBeanNamesForType(Service.class);
for(String beanName: beanNameArray) {
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = factory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);

    beanDefinition.setScope("singleton");
}
```

I hope It can be useful

Comment: Thanks -- is there a way to then override some of the default "request" scoped beans to be singleton scope? As it is in your example, the setScope("request") will change all beans to request scoped, not make request scoped the new default.

Comment: won't your suggestion make *everything* request scoped? What if I still want some singleton scopes? I understand I could do something hacky in my custom RequestScopedPostProcessor -- but it would be nice to say "make each request scoped, unless it already had an explicit scope defined."