# Spring make all beans prototype by default based on configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I have spring beans services defined in  xml which are singleton. They take  a long time to load. What i want a configuration(may be in XML or property file) where
i can make all beans as prototype by default based on that configuration/property so that they can load faster.

Is there any configuration like this in spring ?

Comment: It won't work. Imagine prototype scope of DataSource bean. it means on each request a new instance is created and initialized (with all DB related stuff).

Comment: ok  is there a way i can make bean loading faster ?

Comment: "Make it faster" is nearly *always* an indication of some other fundamental underlying problem. Have you investigated **why** it's "slow"? Are you aware that using prototypes will make your application *slower*?

Comment: Actually i want load single bean per thread not request. That will be fine for me. I know prototype will make it slow thats why i want to do it based on configuration . Like in prod it will be singleton but in dev it will be prototype

Comment: Post your beans, measure which of the beans init is really slow - could be lookups, accesseing some resources? extra calls etc.

Comment: @StanislavL how can i measure which bean is slow to load ? Do i need to use profiler here or is there other way too ?

Comment: Profiling one of the ways. May be exclude something from init (if possible) to see what is slow. Unfortunately I have no clean idea how to figure out the bottleneck in common way.

Comment: @StanislavL we can use SimpleThreadScope(https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-2581) instead of prototype with the solution suggested by Michael. Do you see any concerns here ?

Comment: No you don't want to have something so fundamental different between dev and prod... As it will lead to issues in dev you won't have on prod and vice-versa. So no you don't want that. But as stated here else where, figure out why it is slow (and what is slow in your book?) and tune that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could implement something like this by creating an instance of BeanFactoryPostProcessor as described here: https://dzone.com/articles/changing-default-spring-bean

In that implementation, any beans without an explicit scope would be have prototype scope.

This is similar to this approah (almost a duplicate of your question) [How to specify the default scope in Spring's applicationContext.xml to request scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154353/how-to-specify-the-default-scope-in-springs-applicationcontext-xml-to-request-s)

Note the caveats in that post, however, that this approach does not consider ancestor factories, which may or may not be a consideration in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Load it in Servlet Context in XML configuration, that may help you to speed up singleton object creation, as per my opinion.